# What is my cat doing?

Tags: cats, behavior, vocalizations

My 4 year old keeps doing this. Does anyone know what's going on? (sound on)

https://youtu.be/OWCEf7Gz0ZI

Video description: the cat holds a toy in its mouth, carries it while walking around in a gently arched back posture, casually "wrestles" with the toy in a calm and relaxed way and emits quiet / medium volume yowling sounds.

Comment: He's normally a shy, quiet cat unless he wants food, so something must be exciting him (not "exciting" - he's "assumed castrated" - how it's only "assumed", I've no idea, but that's what his documents say).

Comment: It's only started in the last 6 months, when we got the toy

Comment: Hi, I included a "transcript" of what happens in the video to make the question self-contained; if you don't like my description then please modify as you wish. In short, the sound your cat makes is known as "yowling" and it is common for cats to emit this sound after catching prey, in this case the cat is playing with a toy but for cats playing is most often just pretended hunting.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to dominate the toy in a sexual manner, based on the movement. The preying idea sounds on point, but after dealing with a variety of cats over the years, how the cat is reacting with it's back-end looks like it's attempting to penetrate. Is he fixed?

Comment: I've seen castrated cats "thrust" at blankets like this in a very sexual manner. Maybe some instincts remain even without the hormones? Or maybe the "assumed" castration wasn't done properly (maybe he has a retained testicle) or at all. This happens when feral cats are caught, someone tries to guess whether they're castrated or not based on fur condition, marking behavior and smell of the urine.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Dioxin Yes, well when we got him from the shelter it said he was "presumed castrated". While he's over the toy we've tried to check if he's aroused during but didn't see anything.
Our first impression was it was sexual but I don't know if that's just projection. Anyway it's not harmful behaviour it was more curiosity :)

Answer (score 4):

He apparently is mounting the toy, which isn't that unusual for fixed cats.

The procedure mainly prevents procreation and removes the uncontrollable urge to look for mates, while technically the cat is still capable to 'perform the act'.

I've found cat owners tend to be a bit reluctant to talk about the behavior, but if you ask around openly, you'll find it isn't that uncommon.

It isn't uncommon either for the behavior to start quite a while after the cat has been fixed, our 2 year old boy started about a year after he was fixed.

Our boy has his favorite blanket rolled up into a shape roughly resembling a cat :)

---

*As with any sudden change in behavior, you should consult your vet just to be on the safe side, but it generally is nothing to be immediately concerned about.*